# Куда добавлять зависимости build.gradle(project)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

подскажите куда добавлять зависимости?
Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: Какие зависимости хотите добавить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В новом формате buildscript-зависимости добавляются в виде [плагинов](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) по их идентификатору.

Например, если вы хотите добавить в свой проект плагин [google-services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), то нужно добавить его в секцию `plugins` родительского модуля:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.13' apply false
}
```

И применить плагин в секции `plugins` модуля `app`:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: https://skr.sh/sGjnIJ3d34P

Мне нужно интегрировать в приложение гугл аналитику, но у меня нет таких кодов, которые он предлагает.
Вот как выглядит мой gradle
https://skr.sh/sGj6WaqycoJ

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию о том, какую зависимость вы хотите подключить. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1463109/edit). Текстовую информацию прикладывайте в вопрос в виде текста, не скриншотами.